# Trouble with referencing attributes in Java

Tags: java, object, constructor, attributes

I've been trying to figure out how to pass these attributes from a data class to an executable class correctly but I'm not sure how. Here's the data class:

```
public class Motor {
        private int cylinders;
        private int hp;
        private String type;
        public Motor(int cylinders, int hp, String type) {
            this.cylinders = cylinders;
            this.hp = hp;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public int getCylinders() {
            return cylinders;
        }
        public int getHp() {
            return hp;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Motor: cylinders=" + this.cylinders + ", hp=" + 
                    this.hp + ", type=" + this.type;
        }
}
```

Now, in ANOTHER data class I'm supposed to reference Motor and make a bunch of other attributes. I don't have any(noticeable) errors with this one but I figured none of this would make any sense if I didn't post it:

```
public class Vehicle {
        private String make;
        private String model;
        private int year;
        private double price;
        private Motor motor;
        public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price, Motor motor) {
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.price = price;
            this.motor = motor;

        }
    public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Vehicle make=" + this.make + ", model=" +
                    this.model + ", year=" + this.year + 
                    ", price=" + this.price + ", motor=" +
                    this.motor;
        }
    }
```

This where the real problem is, when I created a Vehicle object in TestVehicle I get an error when I try to add the values for cylinder, hp and type from back in Motor:

```
public class TestVehicle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Toyota", "Corolla", 2015, 15999.0, 7, 300, "Gas");
        System.out.println(v1.toString());

    }

}
```

The error I get when I try to execute it is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Vehicle(String, String, int, double, int, int, String) is undefined

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: The constructor Vehicle(String, String, int, double, int,
>   int, String) is undefined

```
 Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Toyota", "Corolla", 2015, 15999.0, 7, 300, "Gas");
```

change to

```
Motor motor = new Motor( 7, 300, "Gas");
Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Toyota", "Corolla", 2015, 15999.0, motor);
```

Check the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in Parameter passing Constructor of Vehicle. Please try the below code, it is working correctly

```
class Motor {
        private int cylinders;
        private int hp;
        private String type;
        public Motor(int cylinders, int hp, String type) {
            this.cylinders = cylinders;
            this.hp = hp;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public int getCylinders() {
            return cylinders;
        }
        public int getHp() {
            return hp;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Motor: cylinders=" + this.cylinders + ", hp=" + 
                    this.hp + ", type=" + this.type;
        }
}


class Vehicle {
        private String make;
        private String model;
        private int year;
        private double price;
        private Motor motor;
        public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price, Motor motor) {
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.price = price;
            this.motor = motor;

        }
    public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Vehicle make=" + this.make + ", model=" +
                    this.model + ", year=" + this.year + 
                    ", price=" + this.price + ", motor=" +
                    this.motor;
        }
    }

class TestVehicle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Motor m1 = new Motor(7,300,"Gas");
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Toyota", "Corolla", 2015, 15999.0,m1);
        System.out.println(v1.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your constructor, you expecting **String, String, int, double and Motor**.

```
 public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price, Motor motor) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
        this.motor = motor;

    }
```

Your motor has a constructor like:

```
public Motor(int cylinders, int hp, String type) {
            this.cylinders = cylinders;
            this.hp = hp;
            this.type = type;
        }
```

So if you want to pass motor parameters direct as **int, int and String** to Vehicle constructor you need a Vehicle constructor which accept S**tring, String, int, double, int, int, String**.

you can add a second consturctor to you Vehicle class like:

```
public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price, int cylinders, int hp, String type) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
    this.motor = new Motor(cylinders, hp, type);
}
```

But this is not a good style, if something changes you might forget to change both constructors. Better you chaining constructors.

```
public Vehicle(String make, String model, int year, double price, int cylinders, int hp, String type) {
        this.(make, model, year, price, new Motor(cylinders, hp, type))
    }
```